# can I create singletons with in class?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, class, singleton, structure

I want to generate a set of classes/singeltons to access a sqlserver database. I'm aware things like entity-framework exist but I want my own sollution.
Observe the pseudo-code below

```
Class Database
    Dim ConnectionX As SqlClient.SqlConnection
    
    Function getDataTable(Query As String) As DataTable
        Uses ConnectionX
    End Function
    
    ?:Schema1
        Structure Table1
            Dim Field1
            Dim Field2
        End Structure
        
        Function Insert_Table1(Field1, Field2) As Table1
            Uses ConnectionX
        End Function
        
        Function Update_Table1(Field1, Field2) As Table1
            Uses ConnectionX
        End Function        
        
        Sub Delete_Table1(Field1) 
            Uses ConnectionX
        End Sub
```

I want multiple instances of the class "Database" so that I can vary the connection-string to access D, T, A of P
The classes/singletons/structures "Schema" represents the schema's in the database (the '?' above). I do NOT want multiple instances of a Schema.
Within the Schema there are structures that represent tables, views and table-valued-functions in the schema
Under schema I need functions to insert, update and delete into/from a table using the connection from the database.

Can this be done in VB?

Comment: You 're describing (except this: `Dim ConnectionX As SqlClient.SqlConnection`, which you may want to dismiss from the beginning) the combined effort of `TableAdapter`, `DataSet`, + `DataTable` and `DataTable.Schema` (along with their more than tested functionality). Or a mini-ORM as [Dapper](https://dapper-tutorial.net/dapper).

Comment: You know EF exists, but you want to roll your own - just curious why? You didn't take the same approach with e.g. your graphics drivers. Also, "can this be done?" is typically "yes" - could you make your question a bit more specific?

Comment: I'm not using EF because I'm building a general purpose generator that will not only generate code to access databases, but also generates code to create messages, , tooltips, non-volatile variables (in registry/database), userdefined colors etc

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding you correctly, an option would be to make the constructor for the class `Private` and use a `Shared` method to get an instance based on connection string. If an instance already exists for the connection string provided then return that, otherwise create a new instance.

```vb
Public Class Database

    Private Shared ReadOnly instances As New List(Of Database)

    Public Shared Function GetInstance(connectionString As String) As Database
        Dim instance = instances.SingleOrDefault(Function(db) db.ConnectionString)

        If instance Is Nothing Then
            instance = New Database(connectionString)
            instances.Add(instance)
        End If

        Return instance
    End Function

    Public ReadOnly Property ConnectionString As String

    Private Sub New(connectionString As String)
        Me.ConnectionString = connectionString
    End Sub

    '...

End Class
```

You would then do something like this in code whenever you needed an instance:

```vb
Dim db = Database.GetInstance("Data Source=MyServer;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=SSPI;")
```

One thing to keep in mind is that you can actually have effectively equal connection strings that are NOT equal as `String` objects so you might want to use slightly more rigorous comparisons inside your class. I'll leave that decision and implementation up to you though.